# Any Alternatives to Purging Active MQ message queues?

Tags: activemq-classic, wso2-esb

I am new to Active MQ but sometimes the queues are not being processed and keep piling up, Is it a good practice to purge?, Isnt there any other solution that may prevent me from keeping all my messages for reprocessing apart from purging? I really dont want to loose the queues, Is this possible?

Comment: Please, clarify your need, I'm not sure I understand if you ask how to purge amq queues, if you can loose messages or not, if you encounter some performance bottlenecks, if you want to do tuning on amq and or wso2 esb. What does the jms proxy that consume your messages looks like ?, ...

Comment: I am asking whether there is a way to purge without loosing any messages? Because I dont know why the queues get stuck sometimes? I dont know If I am clear?

Comment: Are you talking about moving messages from one queue to another or what do you mean. Can you better explain.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. We have scenarios where the queues are not processed at all, when we restart esb, they start working, but the older ones are not processes. Only the new ones. Is it possible to save these messages somewhere, and re introduce them later to be processed after purging?

Comment: Your usecase is very strange. Are you changing the names of queues in the ESB all the time and still having data in them. This is a weird scenario, which maybe make sense when you explain it. But normally queues are not being filled up as there should always be a consumer - sometime temporally unavailable, but not for a long period. Thanks for clearing up this.

Comment: I don't think the solution is to save messages elsewhere. You should consider tuning amq, esb and your mediation to avoid this piling. Please, show us your proxy def, your axis2.xml jms config, ....  and if you can loose messages, consider Tim Bish answer and set a time to live on your messages.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to deal with this is to set an expiration on messages such that after a given time the broker can discard them.  Letting messages just pile into queues without regard to their lifetime will lead you into all sorts of problems most notably storage.

You need to develop a strategy for how long the messages should live so that the broker can start getting rid of them once they are no longer of use.  If you don't do that then purging the queue is you only option.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Let me work on that. Thanks for the help.